# cocos2d-x 3.6 PhysicsJointFixed error

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am new to cococs2dx and I am working on a code involving PhysicsJointFixed. I am using cocos2d-x-3.6. I am unable to compile the code as I wrote below following the guidelines and the PhysicsTest.cpp.

My GameLayer.h looks like:

```
class GameLayer : public cocos2d::Layer
{
    GameLayer();
    virtual ~GameLayer();

    virtual bool init();

    static Scene* createScene();
    void setPhyWorld(PhysicsWorld* world){m_world = world;}
    CREATE_FUNC(GameLayer);
private:
    PhysicsWorld* m_world;
    ShapeSprite* _square;  //ShapeSprite extends Sprite
    ShapeSprite* _square1;
    PhysicsJointFixed* joint;
    ...
}
```

The createScene method in GameLayer.cpp:

```
Scene* GameLayer::createScene()
{

    auto scene = Scene::createWithPhysics();

    auto layer = GameLayer::create();
    layer->setPhyWorld(scene->getPhysicsWorld());

    scene->addChild(layer);

    return scene;
}
```

Then inside GameLayer::init()

```
bool GameLayer::init()
{
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }
...
...

_square =  ShapeSprite::gameSpriteWithFile("square.png");
auto squareBody = PhysicsBody::createBox(Size(200,200));
_square->setPhysicsBody(squareBody);
_square->setPosition(Vec2(_screenSize.width * 0.5f, _screenSize.height     * 0.7f));

_square1 =  ShapeSprite::gameSpriteWithFile("square1.png");
auto squareBody1 = PhysicsBody::createBox(Size(100,100));
_square1->setPhysicsBody(squareBody1);
_square1->setPosition(Vec2(_screenSize.width * 0.5f, _screenSize.height * 0.7f));

this->addChild(_square);
this->addChild(_square1);

joint = PhysicsJointFixed::construct(_square->getPhysicsBody(), _square1->getPhysicsBody(),Vec2(100,100));

this->getScene()->getPhysicsWorld()->addJoint(joint);

return true;

}
```

The code gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the line
    this->getScene()->getPhysicsWorld()->addJoint(joint);
because, this->getScene()->getPhysicsWorld() returns NULL.

Please advise, how can I avoid the error. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: for more suggestions you should read on these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486310/how-to-access-physics-world-in-layer/38573485#38573485

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because your custom layer is not yet added to scene during `init()`. One possible solution is to override `onEnterTransitionDidFinish()` and add the joint there. In `GameLayer.h` add this:

```
virtual void onEnterTransitionDidFinish();
```

And move the joint adding code to GameLayer.cpp like this:

```
void GameLayer::onEnterTransitionDidFinish() {
    joint = PhysicsJointFixed::construct(_square->getPhysicsBody(), _square1->getPhysicsBody(),Vec2(100,100));

    this->getScene()->getPhysicsWorld()->addJoint(joint);
}
```